# Get an array of objects from an external json file and store as an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I assign a javascript array to that of an array of objects from an EXTERNAL json file?

Here's what I've tried.

**JavaScript Snippet**

```
var i = 0;
var testjson = $.getJSON('/TestJSON');
jsonObj = JSON.parse(testjson);

$("#testJSONBtn").click(function () {
    while (i <= jsonObj.events.length) {
        $("#JSONOutput").append(jsonObj.events[i].title + ", " + jsonObj.events[i].date + ", " + jsonObj.events[i].explanation + "<br/>")
        i += 1;
    }
});
```

**JSON File Contents**

```
{
"events":
[
    {"title":"Okmulgee Public Schools Starts 3rd Quarter" , "date":"1-2-2013" , "explanation":"Okmulgee Public Schools begins its third quarter."}
    {"title":"Okmulgee Public Schools-Closed in Observance of Martin Luther King Jr. Holiday" , "date":"1-21-2013" , "explanation":"The Okmulgee Public Schools will be closed in observance of the Martin Luther King Jr. holiday."}
    {"title":"Okmulgee Public Schools County Professional Day" , "date":"2-1-2013" , "explanation":"Okmulgee Public Schools County Professional Day is today."}
]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For the record, `$.getJSON` is an ajax call.

Comment: ... And it is asynchronous and does not _return_ JSON.  You must do something with it in the success handler

Comment: Did you read the documentation by now: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/? Why did you delete the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14128434/218196)?

Comment: You've shown some code that you've tried. At what point does that code fail to do what you expect? E.g. does testjson contain what it should? What about jsonObj?

Comment: So there's no way to do what I want? External json files are used for what exactly? Not being "smart" I really just don't understand.

Comment: @VoidKing: That's how Ajax works. Receiving the data from an external URL is a non-blocking process. Once the data is received, your code is notified by calling the provided callback. It has nothing to do with JSON itself. Imagine you send your assistant to pick something up from a store. Are you just standing around and wait until he comes back? I assume you continue with your work until he comes back and then deal with whatever he picked up.

Comment: @FelixKling wow. great analogy!

Comment: @Neal: I normally use one involving phones and then the "callback" makes even more sense ;) I should write this down somewhere...

Comment: @LarsH How am I supposed to determine that? All I know is it produces some generic script error that I can't track down. Perhaps you have script diagnostic software that I don't?

Comment: @VoidKing: What's the error message?

Comment: Just as a side note: DOM calls in a loop is a horribly bad thing to do. Use a document fragment to build up the output and append it to the DOM once instead of N times in the loop.

Comment: You would use Firebug or `console.log(...)` statements with the javascript console to show the type and value of testjson and jsonObj. However that's probably not necessary, as Neal has shown the main problem - getJSON does not return the JSON string. However if you're doing javascript programming it would pay you big dividends to learn to use debugging tools.

Comment: @rlemon Okay, don't know how to do that, but thanks for letting me know. Lord knows I don't need to start any bad habits when trying to learn something new.

Comment: @LarsH Ohhh, I'm sure it would, no doubt. But all I know how to use is the simple (and largely uneducational) "inspect element" (or equivalent) that the browser has. Until now, I had never even heard of any console.log statements, and don't even know where to find the javascript console. I should definitely check that out

Comment: @VoidKing [Here are some good resources](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/conversation/javascript-resources). Please take some time to review them. They do not answer your immediate question but they will likely answer some future questions you will have (like you mentioned you're new and learning). Cheers. Remember; crawl before you run.

Comment: For the record your JSON file is missing some commas (not sure if the issue is with the original or the copy/paste).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AJAX functions **do not have data return values**, they just return an AJAX object.

You need to use callbacks.

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('/TestJSON', function(jsonObj){
    $("#testJSONBtn").click(function () {
        for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.events.length; ++i) {
            $("#JSONOutput").append(jsonObj.events[i].title + ", " + jsonObj.events[i].date + ", " + jsonObj.events[i].explanation + "<br/>")
        }
    });
});
```

Better:

```
var btn = $("#testJSONBtn"); //cache the element
var output = $("#JSONOutput"); // ^^^
$.getJSON('/TestJSON', function(jsonObj){
    btn.click(function () {
        var val = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.events.length; ++i) {
            val += jsonObj.events[i].title + ", " + jsonObj.events[i].date + ", " + jsonObj.events[i].explanation + "<br/>";
        }
        output.append(val);
    });
});
```

---

Side point:

I don't know if it was on purpose or not, but in your OP the JSON file does not look legal, you are missing commas. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128700/get-an-array-of-objects-from-an-external-json-file-and-store-as-an-array-in-java/14128734#comment19560739_14128700))

Comment: For what its worth (I may have told you this already, but I don't remember), I fixed the lack of the commas between the objects in my json file (a total of 2 missing commas, if I have that right) and your solution does not work. Again, my path and ids have been double, even triple, checked, and everything is as it should be there. I have tried putting your code in a document.ready jQuery function, outside of said function, and even in a jQuery(function ($) function (just to see), still to no avail. No script errors show. This is why I haven't accepted your answer.

Comment: Just for information's sake, the problem with your code is that you are overrunning the array. The for loop condition should be 'i < jsonObj.events.length' I'm not knocking you, I didn't see it either, and had to be told, myself. Unfortunately at the time of this posting, this error was underneath two others, anyway (my lack of commas and getting IIS express to serve up json files), so they had to be resolved first. Don't know, maybe this will help any future readers. Other than overrunning the array, this code (provided the other errors are taken care of) works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
var testjson = $.getJSON('/TestJSON');
jsonObj = JSON.parse(testjson);
```

`$.getJSON` already parses the JSON into a JavaScript object, and passes it to your callback.

Use this instead:

```
$.getJSON('/TestJSON', function (jsonObj) {
    $("#testJSONBtn").click(function () {
        $.each(jsonObj.events, function (){
             $("#JSONOutput").append(this.title + ", " + this.date + ", " + this.explanation + "<br/>");
        });
    });
});
```

**P.S.** for performance, consider caching your selector, and appending it all in one fell swoop.

Comment: None-constructive comment: Reading your P.S made me question "one fell swoop" or is it "one fowl swoop", so I looked it up. [Interesting stuff to say the least](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/at-one-fell-swoop.html). And now the OP might learn *two* things today. :)

Comment: @Joseph Silber Thanks for trying to help, I appreciate it, but I looked that over, tried it, and not only did it not work, it didn't show any script errors. No external JSON for me. Maybe someone else will ask the question to the satisfaction of the other viewers here and hopefully cause less trolling. Till then I will be voting to close this post (and not asking again, lolz), as it appears to be constructive to absolutely no one (least of all future viewers).

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question states that you wish to "Get an array of objects from an external json file and store as an array in javascript", so my proposed solution involves storing the data in an array.

```
var i;
// Prepare an empty array to store the results
var array = [];
// $.getJSON() is a wrapper for $.ajax(), and it returns a deffered jQuery object
var deferred = $.getJSON('/TestJSON');

deferred.done(function (response) {
    // Any code placed here will be executed if the $.getJSON() method
    // was completed successfully.
    for ( i = 0 ; i < response.length ; i++ ) {
        array.push({ 
            title: response.title, 
            date: response.date,
            explanation: response.explanation
        });
    }
});
```

You can find out more about the returned value of the [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function, and also about using the [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object.

Comment: This is turning into an Abbott & Costello routine. Whacking comments. Please, folks, keep comments on answers relevant *to the answer* in some fashion.